# How could I structure my graphql schema to allow for the retrieval of possible dropdown values?

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to get the possible values for multiple dropdown menus from my graphQL api.

for example, say I have a schema like so:

```
type Employee {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  jobRole: Lookup!
  address: Address!
}

type Address {
  street: String!
  line2: String
  city: String!
  state: Lookup!
  country: Lookup!
  zip: String!
}

type Lookup {
  id: ID!
  value: String!
}
```

**jobRole**, **city** and **state** are all fields that have a predetermined list of values that are needed in various dropdowns in forms around the app.

What would be the best practice in the schema design for this case? I'm considering the following option:

```
query {
  lookups {
    jobRoles {
      id
      value
    }
  }
}
```

This has the advantage of being data driven so I can update my job roles without having to update my schema, but I can see this becoming cumbersome. I've only added a few of our business objects, and already have about 25 different types of lookups in my schema and as I add more data into the API I'll need to somehow to maintain the right lookups being used for the right fields, dealing with general lookups that are used in multiple places vs ultra specific lookups that will only ever apply to one field, etc.

Has anyone else come across a similar issue and is there a good design pattern to handle this?

And for the record I don't want to use enums with introspection for 2 reasons.

1. With the number of lookups we have in our existing data there will be a need for very frequent schema updates
2. With an enum you only get one value, I need a code that will be used as the primary key in the DB and a descriptive value that will be displayed in the UI.

```
//bad
enum jobRole {
  MANAGER
  ENGINEER
  SALES
}
//needed
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Manager"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Engineer"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Sales"
  }
]
```

**EDIT**
I wanted to give another example of why enums probably aren't going to work. We have a lot of descriptions that should show up in a drop down that contain special characters.

```
// Client Type
[
  {
    id: 'ENDOW',
    value: 'Foundation/Endowment'
  },
  {
    id: 'PUBLIC',
    value: 'Public (Government)'
  },
  {
    id: 'MULTI',
    value: 'Union/Multi-Employer'
  }
]
```

There are others that are worse, they have <, >, %, etc. And some of them are complete sentences so the restrictive naming of enums really isn't going to work for this case. I'm leaning towards just making a bunch of lookup queries and treating each lookup as a distinct business object

Comment: If you are concerned about repeating queries and mutations fields all over the app then use apollo fragments.  For example this is for Apollo Angular:  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/fragments/

Comment: I'm concerned about making lots of query endpoints that are specific to fields on my objects, and maintaining documentation as to which query should be used for which field. i.e. if I have jobRole, state, country and 100 other queries to fetch values to be used in dropdowns for possible values to supply to mutations for various objects, how can i structure it to be able to keep track of which query supplies valid options for which field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concerns because GraphQL has only one endpoint, often port 3000 in whatever URL.  I suspect you are still thinking REST, and as I've discovered over the past few months that thinking is a liability.  I created a separate file just for fragments so I can share it among components and this is working super to prevent having to create the same fields over and over in queries and mutations.  It cleaned up my code a lot and gave me a easy to understand place to make changes - DRY.

Comment: I know it only has one endpoint, I’m talking about all the different lookup types on the root query (jobType, state, country, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make enums work the way I needed. I can get the value by putting it in the [description](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Descriptions)

Here's my gql schema definition

```
enum ClientType {
    """
    Public (Government)
    """
    PUBLIC
    """
    Union/Multi-Employer
    """
    MULTI
    """
    Foundation/Endowment
    """
    ENDOW
}
```

When I retrieve it with an introspection query like so

```
{
  __type(name: "ClientType") {
    enumValues {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

I get my data in the exact structure I was looking for!

```
{
    "data": {
        "__type": {
            "enumValues": [{
                "name": "PUBLIC",
                "description": "Public (Government)"
            }, {
                "name": "MULTI",
                "description": "Union/Multi-Employer"
            }, {
                "name": "ENDOW",
                "description": "Foundation/Endowment"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Which has exactly what I need. I can use all the special characters, numbers, etc. found in our descriptions. If anyone is wondering how I keep my schema in sync with our database, I have a simple code generating script that queries the tables that store this info and generates an enums.ts file that exports all these enums. Whenever the data is updated (which doesn't happen that often) I just re-run the code generator and publish the schema changes to production.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use enums for this if you want.

1. Introspection queries can be used client-side just like any other query. Depending on what implementation/framework you're using server-side, you may have to explicitly enable introspection in production. Your client can query the possible enum values when your app loads -- regardless of how many times the schema changes, the client will always have the correct enum values to display.
2. Enum values are not limited to all caps, although they cannot contain spaces. So you can have `Engineer` but not `Human Resources`. That said, if you substitute underscores for spaces, you can just transform the value client-side.
3. I can't speak to non-JavaScript implementations, but GraphQL.js supports assigning a `value` property for each enum value. This property is only used internally. For example, if you receive the enum as an argument, you'll get `2` instead of `Engineer`. Likewise, you would return `2` instead of `Engineer` inside a resolver. You can see how this is done with Apollo Server [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums/#internal-values).

Comment: thanks for the explanation but using the value of a lookup won't work in many of our cases because we have lookup values that contain number, <,>,%, apostrophes, etc. it really does need to be a string field. on top of that i'm using the apollo cli to generate typescript definitions, and that would need to be re-run every time one of those values gets updated as well so I'm really leaning away from enums.